# Mullvad autoconnect bash script

Tags: bash, vpn

I tried to make a bash script that automatically connects to another server (Mullvad) every 40 seconds:

```
locationList=( "al" "tia" "au" "syd" "at" "vie" "be" "bru" "br" "sao" "bg" "sof" "ca" "tor" "co" "bog" "hr" "zag" "cz" "prg" "dk" "cph" "ee" "tll" "fi" "hel" "fr" "par" "de" "fra" "gr" "ath" "hk" "hkg" "hu" "bud" "ie" "dub" "il" "tlv" "it" "mil" "jp" "tyo" "lv" "rix" "mx" "qro" "nl" "ams" "nz" "akl" "no" "osl" "pl" "waw" "pt" "lis" "ro" "buh" "res" "beg" "sg" "sin" "sk" "bts" "za" "jnb" "es" "mad" "se" "mma" "ch" "zrh" "gb" "lon" "ua" "iev" "us" "dal")

for i in {1..100};
do
        randomEvenInt=$((RANDOM % 80)) 
        if ((randomEvenInt % 2 == 0)); 

        then 

            mullvad connect
            randomLocation=${locationList[$randomEvenInt]}
            city=${locationList[$((randomEvenInt + 1))]}
            echo "Connecting to $randomLocation ..."
            mullvad relay set location $randomLocation $city
            echo "Connected to Server in $randomLocation, $city"

        else
            break
        sleep 40

        fi
done
```

each item in an even position in $locationList is an abbreviation for a country and the following item is an abbreviation for the respective city. Sometimes it connects to three, sometimes to two and sometimes just to one server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the question? I see sample code but no explanation of what's wrong with it.

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- OP's issue is that the script processes some small number of city/country pairs before exiting (ie, the `for` loop is not being processed 100 times); if this is the case then the `else break` is being triggered when `randomEventInt` is an odd number
- since the `break` applies to the `for` loop (and not the `if/then/else/fi` block), the `for` loop is not processed 100 times
- as currently written OP's code will never run the `sleep 40`; to `sleep 40` for each pass through the loop OP would want to move the `sleep 40` outside of the `if/then/else/fi` block

While OP could rework the logic to insure an even numbered `randomEventInt` is always generated, I'd probably go with a different approach:

- store the city/country pairs as a single unit in the array
- generate a random number between 0 (index of first item in array) and `N-1` (where
  `N` is the number of items in the array); in OP's case it looks like `N=40`
- upon extracting an array entry we split it into city and country components and make the `mullvad` call

One idea for implementing this new approach:

```
locationList=( 'tia:al' 'syd:au' 'vie:at' 'bru:be' 'sao:br' 'sof:bg' 'tor:ca' 'bog:co' 'zag:hr' 'prg:cz' 'cph:dk' 'tll:ee' 'hel:fi' 'par:fr' 'fra:de' 'ath:gr' 'hkg:hk' 'bud:hu' 'dub:ie' 'tlv:il' 'mil:it' 'tyo:jp' 'rix:lv' 'qro:mx' 'ams:nl' 'akl:nz' 'osl:no' 'waw:pl' 'lis:pt' 'buh:ro' 'beg:res' 'sin:sg' 'bts:sk' 'jnb:za' 'mad:es' 'mma:se' 'zrh:ch' 'lon:gb' 'iev:ua' 'dal:us' )

count="${#locationList[@]}"

for ((i=1; i<=100; i++))                                          # alternative: for i in {1..100}
do
    index=$((RANDOM % count))

    IFS=':' read -r city country <<< "${locationList[index]}"     # split a 'city:country' pair on the ':' delimiter, store results in variables 'city' and 'country'

    mullvad connect
    mullvad relay set location "${country}" "${city}"

    sleep 40
done
```

**NOTES:**

- I don't have the ability to validate the `mullvad` calls; I'll leave it to OP to verify/modify the `mullvad` calls as needed
- OP can add extra code as needed (eg, `echo` calls, error handling, etc)

Comment: Thank you mark!I am new to this community and could not have imagined getting such a quick and detailed response. It works!!